# Is it better to have an entire CMS based website or several static pages and one CMS based webpage?

Tags: static

To propose a more specific scenario. A client wants a 5 page website that includes a blog on that website. I want to know if which would be better; 4 separately made webpages(that don't use a CMS) and one webpage solely CMS based

OR

to create every webpage including the blog using a CMS.

I measure the better method by which ever method will navigate between pages faster. Would it be faster to:

navigate between pages that have all been built via CMS
OR
to navigate between 4 statically built pages and a single CMS built webpage.

Hope you can help
Thanks all
Moe

Comment: What about http://jekyllrb.com/ ? best of both worlds.

Comment: Who will manage the content for the blog?  Do you need a dedicated system for it or would Jekyll or plain old HTML (WYSIWYG) editor do the job?